# =?utf-8?B?R3Vlc3Q=?= <>: missing or malformed local part

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4, smtp

When an order is placed on my site, my cpanel is getting bounced back with

> =?utf-8?B?R3Vlc3Q=?= <>: missing or malformed local part

however I am unsure why this is, and in the admin of magento I have the orders being BCC: to websales@mydomain.com and without an issue I get them.
Magento 1.9

Comment: It's possible the email host is down.  What is the `to` email? `R3Vlc3Q=` decodes to `Guest`, fyi.

Comment: however the contact form emails still work... doesnt that sound a little strange?